# Flutter Firebase RealTime Databasee not ordering properly with OrderByChild()

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, dart

I'm working in an Android app with Firebase RealTime Database.

Currently I'm trying to make this query:

```
List<EmployeeData> employee = await enterpriseRef.child(enterprise).child('employees').orderByChild("surname").once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot){
    print("snapshot value ${snapshot.value}");
    List<EmployeeData> list = new List<EmployeeData>();
    snapshot.value.forEach((k,v){
      list.add(EmployeeData(
        id: k ?? '',
        name: v['name'] ?? '',
        surname: v['surname'] ?? '',
        price: v['price'] == null ? 0.0 : v['price'].toDouble(),
        priceExtra: v['price_extra'] == null ? 0.0 : v['price_extra'].toDouble(),
        priceNight: v['price_night'] == null ? 0.0 : v['price_night'].toDouble(),
        priceHoliday: v['price_holiday'] == null ? 0.0 : v['price_holiday'].toDouble(),
      ));
    });
    return list;
  });
```

I get the data properly, but with an apparently random order. print("snapshot value ${snapshot.value}") gives me this:

snapshot value {192: {price_holiday: 0.0, price: 0.0, surname: Tirado Sanchez, name: Adrià, price_extra: 0.0, price_night: 0.0}, 196: {price_holiday: 0.0, price: 0.0, surname: Gonzalez Navarro, name: Javier, price_extra: 0.0, price_night: 0.0}, 230: {surname: Cantón Casado, name: Rubén}, 198: {price_holiday: 0.0, price: 0.0, surname: Martinez Barreiro, name: Marta, price_extra: 0.0, price_night: 0.0}, 232: {price_holiday: 0.0, price: 0.0, surname: Miranda Muñoz, name: Jose Luis, price_extra: 0.0, price_night: 0.0}, 233: {price_holiday: 0.0, price: 0.0, surname: Calvo Calle, name: Amador, price_extra: 0.0, price_night: 0.0}, 234: {price_holiday: 0.0, price: 0.0, surname: Pedraza Cucala, name: Adrian, price_extra: 0.0, price_night: 0.0}, 114: {price_holiday: 0.0, price: 0.0, surname: Dominguez Malonda, name: Xavier, price_extra: 0.0, price_night: 0.0}, 235: {price_holiday: 0.0, price: 0.0, surname: Rodriguez Jimenez, name: Raul, price_extra: 0.0, price_night: 0.0},

Data isn't ordered by 'surname' but also it isn't ordered by key value. As you can see key values are ordered as 192, 196, 230, 198, 232, 233, 234, 114...
This is exactly the same order I get if I remove .orderByChild("surname") or i change the value of "surname" string at the query. The data at the firebase console UI it show like here:
[image]
And the order i get isn't also the order of the time when the data were inserted. I'm so lost, thanks you for your time :)

Comment: When you call `snapshot.value`, the keys and values are converted to a `Map`, and the keys in a map are inherently unordered. To maintain the order of the nodes, you will need to observe the `onChildAdded` stream, either directly or through the `FirebaseList` class. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49829127/ordering-data-does-not-actually-order-anything/49832827#49832827, https://stackoverflow.com/a/51811808 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/61432966/209103

Comment: Ty for your time Frank, ill take an eye to this. Sorry... I didn't see these posts during my search –

Comment: No worries. I was actually a bit surprised to find how long ago I'd first answered a similar question. :)

Comment: Maybe, you just should add "indexOn : "surname" to employees node from firebase rules side. And then change it to : List<EmployeeData> employee = await enterpriseRef.child(enterprise).child('employees').orderByChild("surname").limitToFirst(1000).....

Comment: Nah, it was added when i was asking it, As Frank said it was because of the map. Fixed now using no map :)