# How do you use a Firebase RTDB sort and filter in a flutter FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

How do you sort and filter results in Flutter when running a query in a Future builder. using OrderbyChild does not seem to work.

I currently have the following as a future:

```
final dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('CarList2').orderByChild('Index').startAt(1);
```

In my Future Builder i then have (Note i am not pasting the full futurebuilder code):

```
FutureBuilder<DataSnapshot>(
                              future: dbRef.once(),
                              builder: (BuildContext context,
                                  AsyncSnapshot<DataSnapshot> snapshot) {
```

What is happening is that the full list comes in a random order rather than being sorted based on the 'Index' field i have in Firebase which assign a sequential numeric number to each unique entry (this is a static list).

Even if i change the field, the order still stays the same and i am expecting the list to be returned in alphabetical order.

Comment: Most likely you're listening to a value event, which in the FlutterFire libraries loses the order. To maintain the info on ordering, you'll want to listen to `.child` events. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49832827, https://stackoverflow.com/a/51811808, https://stackoverflow.com/a/61333575. The last link has a snippet that's the easiest way I've found to maintain order.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, the examples provided are linked to listening to snapshot updates. i have a static list which changes likely once a quarter. is the expectation that we use a firebast list to actually get the index?

Comment: If you want to receive them in order, you'll have to use the `.child` methods which indeed listen persistently. I entered a feature request for FlutterFire to wrap `forEach()`/`children()` from the underlying SDKs, which would expose an ordered snapshot, but that hasn't been implemented as far as I can tell.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, thanks. haven't yet investigate this but will mark this is closed for now