# On Get data(SubChild key) from firebase realtime database using Streambuilder,data is not in order as it was saved

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, flutter-layout, stream-builder

Stream Builder Widget shows items not in order as it's in the Firebase database.
**I have already gone through the solutions such as:**

[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61333194/flutter-firebase-real-time-database-orderbychild-has-no-impact-on-query-result) [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61431601/flutter-items-in-streambuilderusing-firebase-realtime-database-are-sorted-ran) [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51808719/flutter-firebase-database-wrong-timestamp-order) [link4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49829127/ordering-data-does-not-actually-order-anything)

but it did not help as in the link above StreamBuilder with Firebase Realtime database not used.

In firebase It is saved as:

[image: In firebase It is saved as:]

The result on emulator:

[image: The result on emulator]

> List not showing the SubChild Key i.e Date not in the manner as it is saved in the Firebase database.

**The StreamBuilder Widget Code is**

```
new StreamBuilder(
      stream: databaseReference.onValue,
      builder: (context, snap) {
        if (snap.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
          if (snap.hasData &&
              !snap.hasError &&
              snap.data.snapshot.value != null) {
            Map<dynamic, dynamic> data = snap.data.snapshot.value;
            print("data is $data");
            List item = [];
            data.forEach((index, data)=>item.add({
              "key":index, ...data
            }));
            //data.forEach((index, data) => item.add({"key": index, ...data}));
            return item.length == 0
                ? Container(
              alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
              child: new Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Icon(
                    Icons.error,
                    size: 24.0,
                  ),
                  new Text('No Data Found')
                ],
              ),
            )
                : Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: GridView.builder(
                  physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: item.length,
        gridDelegate: new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 3,
        childAspectRatio: 1.0,
        mainAxisSpacing: 2.0,
        crossAxisSpacing: 2.0,
        ),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>new GestureDetector(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: (){
            Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context)=>NavigationBarScreen(item[index]['key'].toString())));
          },
          child: new Card(
            elevation: 4.0,
            color: ConstantColors.PrimaryAssentColor,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(Icons.date_range,color: Colors.white,),
                new Text(item[index]['key'],style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontFamily: 'BlacksOps',)),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        )),
                );
          }
```

Comment: Assuming that you call `orderByKey()` when loading the data, your `snap.data.snapshot.value` converts the results into a `Map` and items in a map are by definition unordered. To maintain the order, you need to listen to `.childAdded` and process the matching child nodes in order. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51811808/, https://stackoverflow.com/a/61333575, https://stackoverflow.com/a/61432966

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen how to use it in StreamBuilder?